# Local Notifications which update their content

Tags: ios6, uilocalnotification

Code:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [components setDay: 3];
    [components setMonth: 7];
    [components setYear: 2012];
    [components setHour: 21];
    [components setMinute: 21];
    [components setSecond: 30];
    [calendar setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSDate *dateToFire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


    UILocalNotification *noti =[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    noti.fireDate = dateToFire;
    noti.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
    noti.soundName = @"chun.aiff";
    noti.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Personal balance: %i", -PB];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:noti];
}
```

The flaw:

If I'm right, I'd say that once this local notification is "embedded" into the device's memory, it sticks with *every local notification* which has been created. I'm I right? If this is true, how can I manage this situation?

Comment: i cant comprehend what you mean by "sticks with every local notification"....  and what is the situation you want to manage??? Kindly explain..

Comment: I was testing the app I'm doing. I tried using different fire dates. Now the app pushes data everyday, at all the moments I set for testing. Not just, say, 12:00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification alert is being repeated because you have used:

```
noti.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
```

Your notification alert is scheduled only for the date you set using date to fire, but the alert is repeated on a day interval as you have set.
Set it to nil if you don't want it to repeat.

Hope it solves your problem.
:)

Comment: I do want it to repeat, but when the user wants it to repeat. If I sun that code every time the user changes the settings, he/she will be flooded with notifications.